Nextjs Pages router - OpenAI GPT assistant not receiving output
I'm working on a codebase that uses the Next.js Pages Router. However, I can't seem to find any documentation supporting the use of the useAssistant hook from the Vercel ai/sdk with the Pages Router. I understand that it's recommended to use the App Router API for this purpose, but for this project, I've been asked to stick with the Pages.
I'm receiving a 200 response from the POST request when connecting to the GPT assistant when I insert an input, however, no output is being returned. Could someone help to resolve this issue? Thanks!
I have the following piece of code in the directory pages/api/assistant/index.tsx
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { AssistantResponse } from "ai";
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY || "",
});

// Allow streaming responses up to 30 seconds
export const maxDuration = 30;

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
  }

  try {
    const input: {
      threadId: string | null;
      message: string;
    } = req.body;

    const threadId = input.threadId ?? (await openai.beta.threads.create({})).id;

    const createdMessage = await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(threadId, {
      role: "user",
      content: input.message,
    });

    await AssistantResponse(
      { threadId, messageId: createdMessage.id },
      async ({ forwardStream, sendDataMessage }) => {
        let runStream = openai.beta.threads.runs.stream(threadId, {
          assistant_id:
            process.env.ASSISTANT_ID ??
            (() => {
              throw new Error("ASSISTANT_ID is not set");
            })(),
        });

        let runResult = await forwardStream(runStream);

        while (
          runResult?.status === "requires_action" &&
          runResult.required_action?.type === "submit_tool_outputs"
        ) {
          const tool_outputs = runResult.required_action.submit_tool_outputs.tool_calls.map(
            (toolCall: any) => {
              const parameters = JSON.parse(toolCall.function.arguments);

              switch (toolCall.function.name) {
                // configure your tool calls here

                default:
                  throw new Error(`Unknown tool call function: ${toolCall.function.name}`);
              }
            },
          );

          runResult = await forwardStream(
            openai.beta.threads.runs.submitToolOutputsStream(threadId, runResult.id, {
              tool_outputs,
            }),
          );
        }
      },
    );

    res.status(200).json({ threadId, messageId: createdMessage.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error handling request:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}


Then I have the output in a component like so components/Statistics.tsx
const { status, messages, setInput, input, submitMessage, handleInputChange } = useAssistant({
    api: "/api/assistant",
  });


  const whatsWorking = messages
    .filter((m) => m.role === "assistant")
    .map((m) => {
      const parsedContent = parseContent(m.content);
      return parsedContent ? parsedContent.whatsWorking : "loading...";
    });

  const whatNeedsImproving = messages
    .filter((m) => m.role === "assistant")
    .map((m) => {
      const parsedContent = parseContent(m.content);
      return parsedContent ? parsedContent.whatsNeedsImproving : "loading...";
    });

  console.log("this is the working message", whatsWorking);
  console.log("this is the working message", whatNeedsImproving);

eturn (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <form onSubmit={submitMessage}>
          <input value={input} onChange={handleInputChange} />
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
        <Box
          info={whatsWorking}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <Box
          info={whatNeedsImproving}
        />
      </Grid>


